# How do I properly access and output API object and array data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

My issue is probably very simple, but I am a complete beginner studying Javascript and I have a project where I am supposed to create an anime info web application by fetching data from an API.

I have an issue with a "genres" category. It is listed as an array with various items and item names which I need to have displayed in a 'Genres' column on my page.
Here is an example of some of the data I need to retrieve.

genres array data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zxcn.jpg

And here is an example of what my current output looks like:

e.g. column output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnYxm.jpg

If I am supposed to accomplish this by means of a forEach loop, what would be the proper syntax? And if there is another or a simpler way, an example of that would also be appreciated.

Here is an example of how I was printing data into their respectful columns through JavaScript.

```
<div className="col-md-8">
  <h2>${movie.title}</h2>
  <ul className="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <strong>Japanese Title:</strong> ${movie.title_japanese}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <strong>Genres:</strong> ${movie.genres}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <strong>Type:</strong> ${movie.type}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <strong>Premiered:</strong> ${movie.premiered}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <strong>Episodes:</strong> ${movie.episodes}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Of course, using "movie.genres.name" returns 'undefined' and just using "movies.genres" would print many [object Object] results into said column.

I would just need the "name" item of the genres array to be automatically filled into my Genres column upon loading up a page.

Comment: `${movie.genres.map(x=>x.name).join(",")}` ??

Comment: @JaydipJadhav This worked perfectly.  I only needed to add a space after the 'join' comma.  I have never used this syntax before so I will need to do a bit of research on 'map' and what it is doing.

Comment: Happy to Help!!

Answer (score 0):

`movie.genres` is an array and you will have to loop it to get each property

```
let output = "";
for(let i=0;i< movie.genres.length; i++){
    output+=  movie.genres[i].name;
}
```

Comment: I was fairly certain this would work and it did bring me a bit closer to what i needed in that it now displayed the correct number of genres per show, but two issues remained. 
[object Object] was still being displayed in my column and my console gave an error saying "movie.genres is not defined".